# A single row background colour

Tags: tables, color

Below is my code. How do I add a background colour to the first row (only the first row, please)?

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c c}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Temperature} [K] & \textbf{Thickness}$[\mu m]$ & \textbf{Permittivity}\\
        \midrule
        $H \# /k$ & K & 17762 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 12):

You can't use `booktabs` with coloured rows as it introduces some vertical spaces around horizontal rules, which will not be coloured. Instead I suggest using `\boldline`, a small package from the `shipunov` bundle, which allows for `hline`s with `variable thickness`. The syntax is `\hlineB{number}` (or `\clineB`), which will  draw a horizontal line with thickness equal to `number × \arrayrulewidth`.

To replace the vertical spacing added by `booktabs`, you can use the `cellspace` package, which can add some minimal vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, boldline} %
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{Sc c c}
        \hlineB{2}
\rowcolor{SeaGreen3!30!} \textbf{Temperature} [K] & \textbf{Thickness}$[\mu m]$ & \textbf{Permittivity}\\
        \hlineB{1.5}
        $H \# /k$ & K & 17762 \\
        \hlineB{2}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Simpy use `\hline` instead of `\toprule`, `\midrule`, or `\bootomrule`. Or set the arrayrulewidth

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table,x11names}{xcolor}%  only needed if you get an option clash
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}    
\def\arraystretch{1.5}% vertical stretch
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}% thicker line
\begin{tabular}{c c c}\hline
\rowcolor{SeaGreen3!30!}\global\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.4pt} 
\textbf{Temperature} [K] & \textbf{Thickness}$[\mu m]$ & \textbf{Permittivity}\\\hline\global\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
$H \# /k$ & K & 17762 \\\hline
\end{tabular}%
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.4pt}% set to old value

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have these packages which clash with you package. Do you know where is the mistake?

Comment: \documentclass{ecsthesis}    % Use the progress Style
\graphicspath{{../Figures/}}   % Location of your graphics files
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}   % Set to false for black/white printing
\input{Definitions}            % Include your abbreviations
\usepackage[sort]{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

Comment: Option clash for package xcolor. \usepackage

Comment: Very probably, xcolor is loaded twice, with different options. Either you load it only once, with all the options, or, if xcolor is already loaded by a package, a simple workaround consists in adding `table,x11names` to the options of the document class, instead of loading xcolor twice.

Comment: Instead of loading the package use `\PassOptionsToPackage{table,x11names}{xcolor}`. see edited answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` which is compatible with `booktabs`. You need two compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[colortbl-like]
        \toprule
        \rowcolor{red!15}
        \textbf{Temperature} [K] & \textbf{Thickness}$[\mu m]$ & \textbf{Permittivity}\\
        \midrule
        $H \# /k$ & K & 17762 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

By use of `tabularray` package which is by library `booktabs` (which call package of the same name) compatible with `booktabs` rules. For units is used `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
%\sisetup{detect-weight}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {ccc},
                 row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=red!15}
                 }
        \toprule
Temperature [\si{\kelvin}] 
            &   Thickness [\si{\micro\metre}]
                &   Permittivity        \\
        \midrule
$H \# /k$   & K & 17762                 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]